# not able to load validation config file in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, validation

I have created an application in CodeIgniter. I'm trying to insert validation in a form. As I will have many forms in my application, so I'm trying to do it with validation config file.

I have created config file in **application/config/form_validation.php**. I have also autolaoded config file by adding **$autoload['config'] = array('form_validation');**

Still, my Validation is not working properly it is always returning **boolean false**

**Below code for the same**

**form_validation.php** file

```
<?php
$config= array(

    'Reservation' => array(
        array(
        'field' => 'name',
        'label' => 'Name',
        'rules' => 'required|max_length[50]|min_length[4]|trim|htmlspecialchars|alpha'
        ),
        array(
        'field' => 'date',
        'label' => 'Date',
        'rules' => 'required|trim|htmlspecialchars',
        'errors'=> ['required'=>'You must provide a %s for the reservation.']
        ),
        array(
        'field' => 'no_people',
        'label' => 'No of People',
        'rules' => 'required|trim|htmlspecialchars'
        )
    )

);
?>
```

**index.php - View**

```
<div class="book-reservation wow slideInUp" data-wow-duration="1s" data-wow-delay=".5s">
                    <?php echo "<script>alert('".validation_errors()."')</script>"; ?>
                    <?php echo form_open('Entry/Reservation'); ?>
                    <div class="col-md-12 form-left">
                        <label><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>Enter Name:</label>
                        <input type="text" name='name' value="<?php echo set_value('name'); ?>">
                        </div>
                     <div class="col-md-3 form-left">
                        <label><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i> Date :</label>
                        <input type="date" name='date' value="<?php echo set_value('date'); ?>">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3 form-left">
                            <label><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i> No.of People :</label>
                            <select class="form-control" name='no_people' value="<?php echo set_value('no_people'); ?>">
                                <option>1 Person</option>
                                <option>2 People</option>
                                <option>3 People</option>
                                <option>4 People</option>
                                <option>5 People</option>
                                <option>More</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
</div>
```

**Entry.php - Controller**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Entry extends CI_Controller {
public function __construct()
{
    Parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('Restaurant');
}
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('index');
    }
    public function Reservation()
    {

        var_dump($this->form_validation->run('Reservation'));
        die;

        if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            redirect();
        }
        else
        {
            #getting values of form
            $data['a'] = array(
            'Person_Name' => $this->input->post('name'),
            'Phone_Number' => $this->input->post('phone'),
            'Reservation_Date' => $this->input->post('date'),
            'No_People' => $this->input->post('no_people'),
            'Reservation_Time' => $this->input->post('time')
            );
            $data['a'] = $this->security->xss_clean($data['a']); #cleaning data
            #calling model
            //echo"<pre>";print_r($data['a']);
            //die;
            if($this->Restaurant->insert_entries($data['a']))
            {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message','Your Reservation has accepted, We will call you back shortly.');
            redirect();
            }

            else
            {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message','Some techincal issue occured, your reservation did not complete.');

            }
        }



    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error in below code as it is not redirecting anywhere

```
if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            redirect();
        }
```

Correct Answer:

```
if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $this->load->view('index');
        }
```